# Want to create "2 tabs with 2 separate webview"

Tags: java, android, webview, tabs, android-webview

I want to create an app consisting of two tabs each of which operates their own webview. I can create tabs but can't manage their webviews.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, fbActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("fb").setIndicator("fb",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_fb))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, google.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("google").setIndicator("google",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_google))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Comment: what you get as an output...

Comment: Your code is correct.  What output you are getting

Comment: i got tabs in output but its not showing me webviews...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create tabactivity class

```
public class tabviews extends TabActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);
    TabHost tab = getTabHost();

    TabSpec tab1 = (TabSpec) tab.newTabSpec("tb1");
    TabSpec tab2 = (TabSpec) tab.newTabSpec("tb2");


    tab1.setIndicator("Customer", null).setContent(
            new Intent(this, webview1.class));
    tab2.setIndicator("Item", null).setContent(
            new Intent(this, webview2.class));

    tab.addTab(tab1);
    tab.addTab(tab2);



}
```

}

then create two activity class say webview1.class and webview2.class

```
public class webview1 extends Activity
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
   WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   v.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

then create another class with same code. enter all three classes in manifest.xml